# Should I uninstall rbenv before installing asdf?

Tags: installation, rbenv, asdf-vm

I wish to install asdf in order to provide for multiple language environments (ruby/python/postgres..) for macOS development.  Previously I have used rbenv to install ruby, and use several ruby gems, including for Cocoapods.  Should I first uninstall rbenv?

Is it also necessary to uninstall ruby version(s) installed with rbenv first, as suggested by a previous SO question?

I have reviewed previous FAQ but advice seems dated and relates to previous versions of shell and version managers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend keeping `rbenv` installed, but forgoing the initialization of rbenv.

For example, if you have something like the following in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```bash
eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init - bash)"
```

Comment that out.

Once you do that, then you can install `asdf`, then initialize it (like it says to do for your system/shell). We comment out the rbenv stuff so only the `asdf` things are in the path, and there is no conflict. But, we don't uninstall rbenv in case you want to go back to using it.